# Spark streaming with delta tables - update input table in microbatch

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, azure-databricks

with two delta tables(tableA, tableB) as input to the streaming pipeline I want to achieve the following:

1. Processing starts when new rows in tableA appear(and not when tableB is updated)
2. mergedTable = tableA.join(tableB, ...., "inner")
3. do some transformations on mergedTable
4. Based on the transformations append new rows to tableB

I started with the following:

```py
tableA = spark.readstream.format("delta").load(path_to_tableA)
tableB = spark.readstream.format("delta").load(path_to_tableB)
mergedTable = tableA.join(tableB, ...., "inner")

def process_microbatch(df, batch_id):
    ...transformations on df...
    df.write.mode("append").saveAsTable(path_to_tableB)

mergedTable.writeStream.foreachBatch(process_microbatch).start()
```

How can I make sure, that only the updates of tableA are triggering microbatch processings? It would be of course also important, that the new rows of tableB are recognized in point 2 within the next batch.

Comment: Instead of doing readstream on tableB you just read it when new records comes to tableA.

Comment: But then, when tableB is appended within process_microbatch, are the new rows going to appear the next time in the join, when new rows appear in tableA?

Comment: You need to process only when tableA got triggered right? Then don't worry about tableB whatever the data tableB having will be used to merge.

Comment: Lets say new rows are appended to tableA. A batch processing is triggered. As a result 2 new rows will be appended to tableB. The next time, when new rows appear in tableA, in the join, will this 2 new rows, coming from the result of the previous batch, play a role? The problem I see is, that tableB is loaded from the delta table only once, at the very beginning, when the stream is started. During the lifetime of the stream, the dataframe tableB is not updated, although the delta table is. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `tableB` is loaded only once at the beginning of the stream and not updated thereafter, any changes made to it within a microbatch will not be reflected in subsequent microbatches. To address this, you need to ensure that `tableB` is reloaded in each microbatch so that it includes the updates made in the previous microbatch.

So, reload `tableB` within the `process_microbatch` function.

Here is the code.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

# Read tableA and apply watermarking
tableA = spark.readStream.format("delta").load(path_to_tableA)

# Define the processing function
def process_microbatch(df, batch_id):

    # Read tableB within the processing function
    tableB = spark.read.format("delta").load(path_to_tableB)
    # Join tables
    mergedTable = df.join(tableB, ...., "inner")
    
    transformed_df = ...
    transformed_df.write.mode("append").format("delta").save(path_to_tableB)


streamingQuery = tableA.writeStream.foreachBatch(process_microbatch)
    .start()
streamingQuery.awaitTermination()
```

By reloading `tableB` within each microbatch, you ensure that any changes made to it in previous microbatches are considered in subsequent microbatches.